# Is there a way to use inner functions without returning them

Tags: python

I'm learning about inner and outer functions, for example:

```
def outer_function(msg):
    def inner_function():
        print(msg)
    return inner_function

hi_func = outer_function("hi")
hi_func()
```

I'm just curious if there is any way to use the inner function inside of the outer function, without returning the inner function, or does it have to be returned to be used?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure ?

Comment: you can certainly call the inner function within the outer function

Comment: Why do you think you have to return the inner function?  Just call it instead of returning it.

Comment: You can always call inner functions within an enclosing function w/o returning them. Just keep in mind hat such inner functions, like all Python objects, have a scope. And whether you should return the inner function or just execute it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are probably looking at an example with @ decorators

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes sense.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Just so you know, you are correct that I was looking at decorators and had not previously seen nested functions before :), I basically wanted to know if those functions were only used for that pattern, or if they had other uses - but I didn't know to phrase it like that until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> any way to use the inner function inside of the outer function, without returning the inner function

Sure. You can just call the inner function.

One reason you might want to do this is to encapsulate part of the logic in a function that doesn't need to be used anywhere else. So you would just create it within the function:

```
def foo(n):
   def generate_rand_num(x):
      import random
      # ... add more logic here to come up with this random num
      return random.randint(0, x)

   a = generate_rand_num(n)
   b = generate_rand_num(n)
   c = generate_rand_num(n)
   return (a+b+c) < n

print foo(123)
```